# Avoid Resolving Forces

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics

I have to do a lot of physics problems, so I frequently have to resolve vectors into x and y components to add them. Is there a different way to deal with vectors, even one that's more complicated? 
Here's an example of the kinds of problems I'm talking about:
[image]

*F1* = 6kN 
*F2* = 2kN 
Both forces act on P. Find the magnitude of the resultant force.
Ans:

1. arctan(12/5) = 67°
2. **F1** = (cos(67°)*6 **i** + sin(67°)*6 **j**) kN
3. **F2** = (-cos(60°)*2 **i** - sin(60°)*2 **j**) kN
4. **Fr** = (1.3 **i** + 3.8 **j**)kN
5. Magnitude = 4.01 kN

Just to specify, I don't need help with this problem, I'm just curious if there's a different way to do it than what I usually do.

Comment: Please. Show us the way you do it.

Comment: @Cesareo Sorry, I am stupid. a. arctan(12/5) = 67; b. F1 = (cos(67)*6 i + sin(67)*6 j) kN; c. F2 = (-cos(60)*2 i - sin(60)*2 j) kN; d. Fr = (1.3 i + 3.8 j)kN

Comment: In this problem, you are only asked to find the magnitude. Do you want an alternative method for just that, or an alternative method for adding the vectors?

Comment: @AHusain An alternate method for adding the vectors, thank you.